# LayoutParams won't properly put ImageViews next to each other

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Currently, I'm trying to make an infinitely long chain of `ImageView`s that are all next to each other. 
I attempt to do this by using `addRule` and `LayoutParam` so that every new `ImageView` has to be set to the right of the `ImageView` before it.

However, I encounter an odd problem. When I do run my code, this is the result :

[image]

Not only are my two `ImageView`s not even next to each other, it doesn't work for any number past two! If I just create two blocks, it gives the result below.

If I make any more blocks than 2, they'll just stack on top of block #2. Which is what happens in the image above.

Also, I have to set every `ImageView` with its own ID because if I don't, they'll all have an ID of -1.

I've been stuck on this for like 5 hours in a row, and it's really starting to get annoying. (Please do not suggest that I use a `LinearLayout`. I already know, and I can't use it.)

```
public class TerrainFactory {

    int count = 0;
    int idCount = 1;
    Terrain terrain;
    public Terrain createNewTerrain(Activity activity, RelativeLayout relativeLayout,
                                    final ArrayList<Terrain> terrainArrayList){
        //TODO: Add the rectangle bounds into this.

        terrain = new Terrain();
        terrain.is = activity.getResources().openRawResource(+R.drawable.game_tile);
        terrain.tile = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(terrain.is);
        terrain.tileDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), terrain.tile);
        terrain.terrainImage = new ImageView(activity);
        terrain.terrainImage.setImageDrawable(terrain.tileDrawable);

        //noinspection ResourceType
        terrain.terrainImage.setId(idCount);
        idCount++;

        if(count >= 1) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);;
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, terrainArrayList.get(count - 1).terrainImage.getId());

            relativeLayout.addView(terrain.terrainImage, layoutParams);
            terrain.terrainImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    //TODO: Set rectangle bounds in here
                    ++count;
                    terrain.terrainImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
        }else{
            ++count;
            relativeLayout.addView(terrain.terrainImage);

            terrain.terrainImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    //TODO: Set rectangle bounds in here
                    terrain.terrainImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });

        }
        return terrain;
    }

    public int getCount() { return count; }
}
```

Here is my `PlayActivity` class, where all the block creating happens :

```
public class PlayActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    TerrainFactory terrainFactory;
    ArrayList<Terrain> terrainArrayList = new ArrayList<Terrain>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        terrainFactory = new TerrainFactory();

            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            terrainArrayList.add(terrainFactory.createNewTerrain(PlayActivity.this, relativeLayout, terrainArrayList));
            }
    }
}
```

And here is the `Terrain` class

```
public class Terrain {

    public Bitmap tile;
    public InputStream is;
    public ObjectAnimator moveLeft;
    public Drawable tileDrawable;
    public Rect bounds;
    public ImageView terrainImage;
}
```

Here's the XML for the `RelativeLayout`. The `RelativeLayout` I'm using is the one nested inside the `RelativeLayout` that fills the entire screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hooray.project.fun.activity.PlayActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"></RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes, you should use `LinearLayout` it is designed for such things, please don't re-invent the wheel

Comment: if for some strange, mysterious ethical reason you dont want to use `LinearLayout` use simple custom `ViewGroup` class

Comment: Well, with a LinearLayout, I couldn't easily make a gap between two images if I wanted to make a hole, not to mention that if I ever set any of the images to VISIBILITY.GONE, the LinearLayout would pull every image in front of it backwards.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html pay attention on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: when changing the margins don't forget to call `requestLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Basically I jsut would tackle this in another way....using not Views for buildiung terrains but using surfaceview and draw bitmaps on it...

But well lets do it your way:

Place your views into a FrameLayout. Then when you create your views give them their dimension in code and also set the x and y positions in code.

For example this is how I give a View the needed Dimension and the position in my Code. Its a Textview and I jsut set the x and y position which I have stuffed iinto variables so I can chnage them how i want:

```
tView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(hintListWidth,hintListHeight));

    tView.setX(hintListPosX);
    tView.setY(hintListPosY);
```

maybe for your example do it like this:

```
float startPosX=???;
float startPosY=???;
float i=0;
for(Terrian t:terrainArrayList)
{
    tView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));
    tView.setX(startPosX+width*i);
    tView.setY(startPosY);
    i++;
}
```

If you have the width and height ready and know where to start placing the first view every view will be placed side by side from left to right...

Comment: Well, that was the solution I originally thought of, but I just feel like that's such a brute-force method to be honest.

Comment: Why is this Brute Force? I dont get it why many want to stick to xml so deep that they jsut spent hours of googling for the right soluttion isntead of making life easy...I mean this is a game app not a normal app in games you just make it this way nevertheless I will try to capture what is wrong in your code maybe....gimme a second I must study your addRule() method as I never worked with it...I update my answer and do a comment when I get the Problem

Comment: Ok I dont really know BUT maybe take the ++count; statement out of the listener like when count is 0 . That would explain the behaviour. Maybe count is allways 1 and you set all the views just at the right of the countID 0 ... There you dont have the increment inside the listener so try this out

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing statement and out of context things basically: Try to increment the count outside of the if statements like when you increment the Id...maybe use the Id also as the count referring to the amount of views as Id+1?

Comment: but I dont exactly know if it solves the problem because im obviously coonfused about the usage of count and idCount and also that you have listener for no reason at the moment plus making increment outside of listener in else but then making inside a listener on the if statement so...yeah I tried to understand and help afterall^^

Comment: The listener automatically activates as soon as the object is actually drawn and resized by the RelativeLayout, because if I try to do operations on the ImageView before the listener kicks in, it will always return 0 for the X, Y, left, top, right, bottom, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answer(s) to your question, the problem is that counter on the `if-true` branch is never incremented **before** views are drawn (aka tree observer callback being called). You are calling `addView` but I think this goes on and adds the view asynchronously, while you go on and add views. So you finish adding the views and only after that they are drawn. I suggest taking the counter out of the callback and place it at the end of the if-true block.

*Note*: if you are targeting SDK17+ you can use `View.generateViewId()` instead of manually keeping track / incrementing it yourself. Not that it matters in this particular scenario, but it will not allow the generated id to conflict with aapt-generated ids and it will roll it over once the top limit is reached.